# Is there a correct order of "conv2d", "batchnorm2d", "ReLU/LeakyReLU", "MaxPool2d" for UNet like architectures?

Tags: convolution, batch-normalization, pooling, encoder-decoder

**Context**

I'm investigating the UNet architecture for a little while now. After investigating the structure of the official UNet architecture as proposed in the official paper I noticed a recurrent pattern of **Conv2d->BatchNorm2d->ReLU(->MaxPool2d)->Conv2d->BatchNorm2d->ReLU(->MaxPool2d)** for the encoder part but I have also came across other implementations of a custom UNet where this order is different like **Conv2d->BatchNorm2d->ReLU(->MaxPool2d)->BatchNorm2d->Conv2d->ReLU(->MaxPool2D)** where the operation in the paranthesis is considered optional.

I've tried training both models and they both work reasonably well but I still want to understand the following:

**Question**

1. Is there a "correct" order for these operations for the encoder/decoder part of the UNet architecture?
2. What is the intuition behind shifting the order of these operations in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to follow the official [U-NET](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) implementation.

To me, the second option `Conv2d -> BatchNorm2d -> ReLU (-> MaxPool2d) -> BatchNorm2d -> Conv2d -> ReLU (-> MaxPool2D)` seems more a mistake that an alternative:

- The part `-> BatchNorm2d -> ReLU (-> MaxPool2d) -> BatchNorm2d ->` doesn't make much sense: the first BN already centers the activation then max-pool takes only the max that doesn't introduce any substantial change in distribution, so the second BN in my opinion is not that much necessary.
- The following part `-> Conv2d -> ReLU (-> MaxPool2D)`, now, lacks the BN operation which should be put in between `conv2d` and `ReLU`.

So I suggest you to follow the `Conv2d -> BN -> ReLU (-> MaxPool)` design. At the best you can swap `BN` with the activation (i.e. `conv -> relu -> BN`): there is a debate about this regarding BN, some people think is better some other that's equivalent..

> Is there a "correct" order for these operations for the encoder/decoder part of the UNet architecture?

The correct order, is the first option you specified.

> What is the intuition behind shifting the order of these operations in the model?

At most it can be motivate by re-normalizing again (by means of BN) the activation or even the max-pool's output. But if so, there are two missing BNs: after the second ReLU and max-pool.